# Why are my FactoryBots not creating ID's or timestamps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, faker

Defining the Flashcard Bot

```
FactoryBot.define do
    factory :flashcard do
        question { Faker::Quote.matz }
        time { Faker::Number.between(from: 1, to: 300) }
        association :box
    end
end
```

Defining the Box Bot

```
FactoryBot.define do
    factory :box do 
        mod_p { Faker::Number.between(from: 1, to: 10) }
        box_number { Faker::Number.between(from: 1, to: 10) }
    end
end
```

Making boxes and flashcards in my test

```
box1 = FactoryBot.build(:box, box_number: 1)
box2 = FactoryBot.build(:box, box_number: 2)
box3 = FactoryBot.build(:box, box_number: 3)

subject(:flashcard) {FactoryBot.build(:flashcard, box: box2)}
```

For some reason they are being created without ids or timestamps?? anyone have any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05yjv.png)

Have found some links online about Rails 6 but this is not the case with my project. I am using rails 5.2

Comment: Because `build` just builds a record. If you want to create one you can use `create`

Answer (score 0):

@engineersmnky's comment is the correct answer. Feel free to vote for it and not this. But, I thought I'd add a bit more context.

Assigning an id is something the database does upon record creation. Adding the timestamps is something Rails does for you just before it writes the record to the database. (Check your Rails logs. The timestamps should show up as part of the `CREATE` SQL statements.)

`FactoryBot.build` instantiates an instance of the record in memory. It's best to use this when optimizing for test suite performance.

`FactoryBot.create` writes the record to the database. It's best to use this when your system uses ActiveRecord hooks to take action before or after something is written to the database, or when your test needs will later query the database to find the record you just created with FactoryBot.

PS - The more you can use `.build` the better. Not only will your test be more performant. But, you'll be discouraged from coupling your tests to the database.